# Manipulating TreeView With CheckBox

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView with checkbox. I have seen a few examples online to show how to bind parent/child checkbox together using INotifyPropertyChanged.
However, what I am trying to achieve is something more than that.

Assuming I have 2 different object

**Main Object**

```
public class MainObject
{
    public string Name;
    public List<SubObject> SubObjects;
    public bool? IsChecked;
    //other parameters
}
```

**Sub Object**

```
public class SubObject
{
    string Label;
    public bool? IsChecked;
    //other parameters
}
```

**TreeView Display**

```
- Main_Object_1(Name)
    - Sub_Object_1(Label)
    - Sub_Object_2(Label)
- Main_Object_2(Name)
    - Sub_Object_3(Label)
```

I have 3 objectives:

**1) Parent/Child checkbox association**

Main Object and sub object will reflect the correct status depending on which checkbox is clicked.

If Main object checkbox is checked, all the sub object will be checked.

If one of the sub object is checked, main object will be null (fully filled with some color)

**2) Different set association**

At any one time one set (Main_Object_1 or Main_Object_2) can be checked.

Assuming only "Main_Object_2"and "Sub_Object_3" is checked. 
When check on "Main_Object_1" or "Sub_Object_1" or "Sub_Object_2", "Main_Object_2" and "Sub_Object_3" is unchecked.

**3) Performing other task beside updating the checkbox display**

I will need to perform other task depending on which node is checked/unchecked.

Any pointer on how to get this done?
Thanks.

Comment: if  class data attributes are declared as fields (`public bool? IsChecked;`) you won't even be able to display them via binding. however if they are properties (`public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }`) you can write *any* logic in setter and implement requirements 1.2.3. with some effort invested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get out the output I wanted by adding a IsChecked property and parent property and Set property. After which I added some logic to manipulate the checkbox status. For objective 3, I simply add a checked event handler to perform the task I needed.